# How to make matplotlib svg export respect bounding box in a viewer safe way

Tags: python, svg, matplotlib, export, bounding-box

Whenever I do a svg export and I have used a set_xlim or set_ylim earlier the complete curve gets visible in the svg (output on the right below). At least this happens as long as I open the file with ubuntu image viewer. Inkscape for example opens the svg perfectly well. Unfortunately I newer know with what application people I send figures to are going to use for opening. Is there any way to suppress this behaviour and that "cuts" the curve at the bounding box for any viewer?

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.ion()
plt.plot(np.random.random_integers(0,100, size= 50))
plt.gca().set_ylim((10,50))

plt.gcf().savefig('test_pdf.pdf')
plt.gcf().savefig('test_svg.svg')
```

[image]

Comment: Presumably the ubuntu viewer is buggy. I don't see how an application can be written to account for all bugs in all SVG viewers.

Comment: most probably you are right, I just checked a few html editors and they show it the right way as well...

Comment: Presumably the ubuntu viewer has a bugtracker you could report the fault to.